# Get all records order by date and time and with limits

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

In my website there's a page to display all the records in a table. So, I have a simple pagination mechanism.

For the pagination, I'm querying the table with limits according to the page.

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM records ";
$query .= "LIMIT $start, $limit;";
```

This works perfectly for me.

However, the order I need to get records is not the order of the table. It's should be according to the **date and time** of the records. (There're columns for date and time).

So, when I changed the query to this, it always gives me same records in every page.

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM records ";
$query .= "WHERE published = '1' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC ";
$query .= "LIMIT $start, $limit;";
```

What I need is, all the records should order by **date and time** and they should also respect to `$start` and `$limit` variables.

It's basically the actual way pagination works. How to implement it with this..

Comment: It should work. Ho do you populate `$start` and `$limit` ?

Comment: Is your current query not working?

Comment: The current one is the 2nd one. It's working but, it gives the doesn't paginate properly.

Comment: You need to calculate that $start,$limit at your application end for each batch.

Comment: Thanks all I got it working! :) It was my bad that hadn't set limits correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard pattern for this is something like

```
$itemsPerPage = 10;
$page = (int) $page; // get $page from route or $_GET['page'] or wherever
$pageNum = (!empty($page)) ? (int) $page - 1 : 0;
$start = $pageNum * $itemsPerPage;

$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM records ";
$query .= "WHERE published = '1' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC ";
$query .= "LIMIT $start, $itemsPerPage;";
```

Remember its start plus number of items, not start to end.

Comment: Thanks all I got it working! :) It was my bad that hadn't set limits correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your $start and $limit are each numbers, like $start = 1, $limit = 50, after each page, increment both $start and $limit by $limit, so `$start += $limit`, and `$limit += $limit`.  This should have the effect of moving $start and $limit to the next page worth of records.